# Usage of "go" in instructions

Tags: word-usage

Can I use "go" to say:

> Please first select a default folder by **going to** Tools > Options > Home Folder

Comment: Seems okay. "go" is used in computing. I don't think there is an issue.

Comment: It is perfect! You can also use *navigate to* or *navigating to* in your context: _Please first select a default folder by ***navigating to*** Tools > Options > Home Folder_ There is no problem with "go/going to." :)

Comment: Or "Please first go to a default folder by selecting Tools > Options > Home Folder".

Comment: **"Start by going to"** is Tech Support 101, Ahmad!

Answer (score 1):

Yes; "go" is often used in this way. However, it's probably clearer to say "select" or "navigate to" in the case of menus in software.

Side note: If you are the creator of the software using this menu, may I suggest making a settings dialog which is accessed via "Edit -> Preferences" or the like? Or (even better), since these instructions seem to be for something the user should do once (setting a default option), perhaps you could prompt them to do it when they open the software. (Something like "Please select a default folder.")

Comment: Thank you for your advice, yeah I could ask them to select one, or I can select a default directory myself (for example MyDocuments) and let them change it!